# Routes won't work for form_tag helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm a Rails 3 newbie so I must be doing something stupid here as almost all my routes are not working with the form_tag helper. I've broke it down to the simplest example:

```
<%= form_tag(choose_devices) do %>
<% end %>
```

Rake routes is showing the route:

```
choose_devices POST   /account/devices/choose(.:format)
{:action=>"choose", :controller=>"devices"}
```

The error I'm getting when trying to load the page is:

```
undefined local variable or method `choose_devices' for
#<#<Class:0x00000100d8e270>:0x00000100d7efa0>
```

I tried various routes to test with and it only seems to work with this one:

```
user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)
{:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`choose_devices` is your named route.  Rails automatically generates two methods per named route as route helpers for you.  They are always named in the following convention:

```
named_route_path
named_route_url
```

You can use either (although path is usually encouraged).  Using `choose_devices_path` will return `/account/devices/choose` whereas `choose_devices_url` will return something like `localhost:3333/account/devices/choose` or it actually may error out if you do not set your host appropriately in config files (it's been a long time since I explicitly used a `_url` named route helper, so not sure on that part).

You can also read up on these specifically at the [rails routing guide.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#paths-and-urls)

Answer (score 1):

You need to append _path ie.

```
choose_devices_path
```